# How can I .toggle("flip") only the parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a beginner at JavaScript. Below is some code I found on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLhgT/65/)

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.button', function() {
     console.log("CLICK");
     document.querySelector('.card').classList.toggle("flip");
});
```

I'm trying to have multiple elements that can flip individually. I want to use a button inside that element to trigger the flip of only that parent element. I don't know where to start so I really hope that you guys can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector):

> Returns the first element within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that matches the specified group of selectors.

You current code always toggles the *first* `.card` element in the document.

You want each card's button to flip that card. You know that the card is the ancestor of the button that you want triggering its flip, so when a button is clicked, flip that button's ancestor of class `card:`

```
$('.button').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('.card').toggleClass("flip");
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nLhgT/69/)

Notes:

- I changed your selector from `document.body` to only `.button` elements. To select all **buttons** (allowing you to remove `class="button"`, remove the period (i.e. `$('button')`
- `.closest('selector')` returns the nearest ancestor elements in that selector group
- `.toggleClass()` is cleaner than `.classList.toggle()`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the good explanation trojan! I already made something like this about an half hour ago but it still didn't work! I think because i didn't know what i was doing exactly. You've made it so much clearer for me! :)

Comment: @AronMartin Glad I could help. If you don't want to include the jQuery library, emphaticsunshine's answer will do what you want in pure, native JavaScript. (The only thing you have to worry about with that method is if you change your HTML layout so that the cards aren't exactly grandparents of the buttons.)

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for native js solution. This is the way to go:

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons.item(i).addEventListener("click", function () {
         this.parentNode.parentNode.classList.toggle("flip");
    });
}
```

Comment: One part being native JS does **not** make it native JS. This still relies on jQuery. Edit it to use `getElementsByClassName()` and `onclick = function() {`, and I'll upvote this as a useful answer.

Comment: The only thing he is using jQuery is for event binding. If you are a js developer, you know you don't need to use a library for just event binding.

Comment: That's true; however, you can't claim that this is pure JavaScript. OP has stated that he's a beginner; what's to stop him from taking your word that this is native? Update: good answer. +1

Comment: @trojansdestroy is it fine now? The reason I started native implementation because he used document.querySelector. I didn't event look at the event handler.

Comment: @trojansdestroy: I appreciate your previous response :)

Comment: Actually, just noticed something. `button` is an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) returned by [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName); you'll want to loop through to add the listener to each element individually.

Comment: I suggested [this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3761950) to your answer, correcting the code (with demo), but it was rejected; consider editing your code to loop through `button`.

Comment: @trojansdestroy, thank you for suggestion. I figured out that myself later but was lazy to change it :P